# JavaScript jwplayer not playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I built a script using the jwplayer to Play an rtmp stream in my browser but somehow if I click on Play nothing happens.

I get this message above my Player: error loaidng Player: noplayable sources found.

In my html I have a Basic div like this:

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

My script so far:

```
var data = [];
var jw_width = 1900,
    jw_height = 1080;

// Outputs some logs about jwplayer
function print(t, obj) {
    for (var a in obj) {
        if (_typeof(obj[a]) === "object") {
            print(t + '.' + a, obj[a]);
        } else {
            data[t + '.' + a] = obj[a];
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    jwplayer('player').setup({
        wmode: 'transparent',
        width: jw_width,
        height: jw_height,
        stretching: 'exactfit'
    });

    $('#restart-stream').click(function () {
        jwplayer('player').stop();
        startPlayer("rtmp://31.151.24.38:1935/app/stream");
    });

    $('#stop-stream').click(function () {
        jwplayer('player').stop();
    });
});

// Starts the flash player
function startPlayer(stream) {
    jwplayer('player').setup({
        height: jw_height,
        width: jw_width,
        stretching: 'exactfit',
        sources: [{
            file: stream
        }],
        rtmp: {
            bufferlength: 1
        }
    });
    jwplayer("player").onMeta(function (event) {
        var info = "";
        for (var key in data) {
            info += key + " = " + data[key] + "<BR>";
        }
        print("event", event);
    });
    jwplayer('player').play();
}
```

Comment: What version of JW Player are you using?

Comment: I get following in my console `jwplayer.version
"7.10.4+commercial_v7-10-4.169.commercial.85c759.jwplayer.c6ac25.freewheel.54b0c5.googima.e3d790.vast.21749a.analytics.4bea33.plugin-gapro.7e936b.plugin-related.ce6086.plugin-sharing.e6b540.vr-plugin.d532d3.hls.js."`

Comment: @jherrieven any ideas ? :)